# VBA Resizing a Current Region to omit bottom row

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I use the below code to sort a `.CurrentRegion` numerically. However the bottom row of this range is the SubTotal, and as such I do not want it to be included in the sort, and it must remain the bottom row after the sort has happened. I am struggling to resize the `.CurrentRegion` prior to the sort to not include the bottom row.

I have tried resizing it but it doesn't seem that you can resize a CurrentRegion? This is what I tried: `With .Cells(rw, 7).CurrentRegion.Resize(-1, 0)`

```
Dim j As Long, rw As Long
   rw = 1
   With Worksheets("Export_Bets")
        Do While rw < .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            With .Cells(rw, 7).CurrentRegion
               With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 2)
                    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                                Key2:=.Columns(1), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                               Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RowSize` propery represents the number of rows, and **NOT** as you are using it, a change in the number of rows.

So you would need something like

```
With Cells(rw, 7).CurrentRegion.resize(rowsize:=Cells(rw,7).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)
```

or

```
    With Cells(rw,7).CurrentRegion
        With .resize(rowsize:=.Rows.Count - 1)
```